# Not able to scroll to see old inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Look at this chat example here. https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-chat. All the code is available in the link as well.

After typing many messages the old messages dissapears in the top and it's not possible to scroll in order to see the old ones. So how can I introduce a scroll such that I can see very old messages as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy! Have a look:

**Your HTML**

I am using jQuery to make everything cleaner and so I needed to include the script. I have also added an ID to `ul`.

**Your CSS**

Added `overflow: auto` and `height` properties. Basic!

**Your JS**

It's as simple as

```
$("#123").animate({ scrollTop: $('#123')[0].scrollHeight }, 500);
```

Have a look here at my [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzybMJ).

Comment: If you're way at the top in a chat, you'd want to decrease the time for animate further down to say 50.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `overflow` & `height` property to `ul`s parent element (named '`#innerFrame` in my case) element, like:

```
#innerFrame {
  height: 406px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

And to scroll to bottom of `div` everytime you press enter, use the following script:

```
var height = 0;
$('.frame ul li').each(function(i, value){
    height += parseInt($(this).height());
});

height += '';

$('#innerFrame').animate({scrollTop: height});
```

Have a look at this **[Demo Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/przMoZ)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That solved the scroll problem but it also makes the chat bubbles to start in the top of the window instead of starting right above the input typing field. But thanks for the scroll tip anyways :).

Comment: @Joey_D I've updated the [**PEN**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/przMoZ), have a look at it. Please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: @SauravRastogi Just imagine the amount of calculation and that too for every new message involved when the chat has become quite lengthy!

Comment: @Saurav Rastogi When using this code the chat message ends up at the top of the page for the first few messages. In that regard the original code worked better because then the newley written chat message ended up just above the input field, always.